# Iterate a Map<String,Integer> in order of second operator (integer) [JAVA]

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

```
Map<String,Integer> map;
map.put("hey",1); 
map.put("k",0); 
map.put("thanks",12);
```

How can I iterate the map entries in order of the second operator (the numbers)?
thanks

Comment: I meant: Map<String,Integer> (left operator is a String and the right is Integer)

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: LinkedHashMap but it didn't work because I do not put the items in order

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("hey",1); map.put("k",0); map.put("thanks",12);
    map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((x, y) -> x.getValue() - y.getValue())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

resullt:

```
k=0
hey=1
thanks=12
```